# How add frame around video

Tags: android, video, processing

I'm developing app in which I need to create video with frame around it. So, basically i get video throuh standart camera and then I need to add frame around it. On the picture my video needs to be instead of blue area;[image]

I have already read a tons of information about video processing and post-processing, opencv, ffmpeg etc. Does anyone knows how I can achieve this ?

Comment: You need to provide more information before anybody can attempt to help you. Are you for example going to upload to YouTube and you maybe want to have a view with your video embedded, and add a blue border... Or is the video on local storage? The possibilities are endless. You need to be more specific or your question is going to get flagged as too broad.

Comment: i need to get a video with overlaid frame on it. I already know that i need to use ffmpeg to achieve what i want. And i dont understand why you asking about youtube, there wasn't any word about it.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours I found only one solution - to use ffmpeg. You can build it and use through android jni. In my case I used executable ffmpeg file. In  OnCreate I'm installing it from raw and then using its functions. (There are many solutions in the internet and on the StackOverflow about ffmpeg commands)

Answer (score -1):

This is very simple. 
Try to understand what I have written.

```
PImage frame, temp;
void setup()
{
/*Display your frame here*/
frame = get(); // this will capture the screen
}
void movieEvent(Movie m)
{
m.read();
frame.copy(m, 0, 0, m.width, m.height, Xbluestart, Ybluestart, Xblueend, Yblueend);
}
void draw()
{
Image(frame, 0, 0);
}
```

I think this would slove your problem.
P.S. instead of writing Xbluestart or Xblueend; write the co-ordinates of blue rectangle in there.

Comment: I don't think this will work on Android. Or if it will, you need to actually expand the code sample to show the view class you are extending and so on. I've been working with Android for three yeas and I couldn't turn this into a working example. I just spent 30 minutes trying...